# How to airdrop an eosio token

Tags: eosio.token, airdrops

I am trying to create a new eosio token and airdrop it at a 1:1 ratio to all eosio accounts.  I have a snapshot csv file with all the eosio account names, the public key, and EOS token balances.  My idea to airdrop is as follows:

1. create an account to issue the new token
2. create the new token with the eosio.token contract, using the account created above as the issuer
3. create a script that iterates over every account in the snapshot and issues my new token to each account at a 1:1 ratio with the eos tokens each already has.

I'm thinking I could make a short python script that reads the csv file, and then does an os call

`'cleos push action eosio.token issue '["<account-from-snapshot","<new-quantity-based-off-snapshot","issuing new token"]' -p <my-issuer-account>'`

for every account in the snapshot.

Has anyone done an airdrop before and could weight in on this procedure?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you ever think that you need to pay the RAM for each user you are airdropping? I'm having this dilemma right now, still thinking about a solution like a redeem/claim airdropped tokens.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. Looking at the eosio.token contract, when you send new tokens to an account `add_balance( to, quantity, from );` the the sender `from` pays for the RAM `to_acnts.emplace( ram_payer/*from*/, [&]( auto& a ){ a.balance = value; });`. then once they have tokens the RAM paying account remains the ram payer `to_acnts.modify( to, 0, [&]( auto& a ) {`.  The issuing account would have to pay for everyone.  Going with your idea, I guess you could write a contract where a user would have to send some EOS to in order to get new token.  Idk if devs are doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the airdrop tools available: https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops

They do [something similar to what you suggest](https://github.com/EOSEssentials/EOSDrops/blob/master/services/EOSTools.js#L182-L185) but they optimise the process and provide a configuration interface.

Edit: New tool that stores daily snapshots: https://www.eossnapshots.io/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much easier method: https://eos.discussions.app/e/mothereos/7185907905/Mom_Airdrop_to_SHipple_Basecamp_group_on_FB

You can use copy and paste and excellor google docs, edit and replace and take out that SHIl token replace with yours and the amount you want then just copy and paste that list as just a com